# set('post__not_in', array(ВСЕ_ПОСТЫ) );}

Tags: wordpress

Хочу в WP не выводить ВСЕ посты в определенных категориях.
Делаю так

```
function exclude_post($query) {
    if ($query->is_category(array(тут ID категорий, в которых не нужно выводить посты))) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', array(**КАК ЗДЕСЬ ПРОПИСАТЬ УСЛОВИЕ ВСЕХ ПОСТОВ**) );
    }
    return $query; 
 }
 add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_post');
```

Или может есть другое решение?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `category__not_in`:

```
function exclude_post($query) {
    $query->set( 'category__not_in', array(2,6) );
    return $query; 
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_post');
```

В данном примере будут выведены все имеющиеся посты, кроме всех тех постов, что входят в категории 2 и 6.

Comment: category__not_in получают посты, которые не входят в указанную категорию. А мне нужно, чтобы в определенных категориях не выводились никакие посты.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Поясните на примере, а лучше, попробуйте в коде.

Comment: Хочу в WP НЕ выводить ВСЕ посты в определенных категориях.

Comment: Это давно понял. Согласно описанию, "category__not_in(массив) - 
Получить посты, которые не входят в указанную категорию." Вы пробовали использовать этот аргумент в запросе?

Comment: Я в массиве (в своем примере кода вверху) хочу указать абсолютно все посты, которые есть и будут. Чтобы они не выводились в определенных категориях. Как в данном контексте использовать category__not_in я не знаю.

Comment: Полный текст вашей функции поместил в ответ. Сделал пример у себя на тестовом сайте. Конечно, 'category__not_in' работает в соответствии с описанием!

Comment: Мне не нужно выводить посты. Мне нужно НЕ выводить посты в определенных категориях, т.е. совсем, чтобы посты не выводились в них.

Comment: ДА, именно это и происходит. Прекратите бесплодную дискуссию. Поработайте уже с кодом. Я уже за вас все тестовые примеры сделал, все работает.

Comment: Не работает. Как выводились посты в категориях так и выводятся.

Comment: Покажите запрос целиком. Как строится wp_query. Поскольку у меня эта конструкция работает прекрасно, то ошибка у вас в другом месте.

Comment: Я просто добавляю ваш пример в конец function.php

Comment: И что дальше? Какие посты вы собираетесь выводить? Какой плагин или тема формирует запрос WP_Query? Вы показываете кусок кода, который, как я полагаю, у вас работал до обращения на SO, и вы захотели его модифицировать, убрав ненужные категории. Или это не так? Опишите, пожалуйста, ситуацию полностью, создав минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Зайдите сюда: http://test.kagg.eu/3/ и вы увидите, что справа, в виджете recent_posts этот пост (3) отсутствует. Потому что в конце functions.php этого сайта стоит код из моего ответа. Строка 2 выглядит так: `$query->set( 'category__not_in', array(26) )`, потому что категория `Блог`, в которую входит этот пост (3), имеет id=26. То есть код из ответа убирает все посты с категорией 26 из виджета справа на странице сайта.